# ValidateAntiForgeryToken is failing from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, antiforgerytoken

***EDIT: I have tried a few more things .. see end of this question for updates***

I'm trying to pass some data, along with the AntiForgeryToken, from a page in my MVC application to a controller via AJAX. This is not the only place I'm doing this, but this is the first place where it's not working.

The java side of my code is:

```
var dirtyFields = [];

$('.DirtyField').each(function () {
    var newValue;

    if ($(this).is('select'))
        newValue = $(this).val();
    else if ($(this).is('input[type="text"]'))
        newValue = $(this).val();
    else
        newValue = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 'true' : 'false';

    dirtyFields.push({
        FieldName: $(this).attr('name'),
        OldValue: $(this).attr('data-oldvalue'),
        NewValue: newValue
    });
});

var token = $("#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input").val();
var dataObject =
    {
        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
        MaintUserId: $('#HiddenMaintUserID').val(),
        ChangedFields: dirtyFields
    };

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveDataAction", "SomeController")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'json',
    data: dataObject,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    if (result.Success == 'true') {
        alert("User information was updated successfully!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Update failed!");
    }
```

On the controller side of my application is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult SaveDataAction(SaveDataHelper dataObject)
{
    return Json(new { Success = "true" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

The definition of SaveDataHelper is:

```
public class SaveDataHelper
{
    public int MaintUserID { get; set; }
    public List<DataItemHelper> ChangedFields { get; set; }
}

public class DataItemHelper
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string OldValue  { get; set; }
    public string NewValue  { get; set; }
}
```

Breaking into my javascript, at the time of the ajax call the variable dataObject contains the following:

```
Object {__RequestVerificationToken: "Long-string-of-characters", MaintUserId: "9", ChangedFields: Array[1]}
```

ChangedFields contains the following:

```
0: Object
    FieldName: "MiddleName"
    NewValue: ""
    OldValue: "S"
```

When I get the error, I look at the jqXHR in the console and find this at the top of the responseText:

```
[HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery form field &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present.]
```

This code is similar to code all over my application. The only difference here is that I'm passing an array in the dataObject (this is the first time I've needed to do that).

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Because of the questions about the AntiForgery Form .. I have (in Chrome) gone to the View Page Source and pasted the TOP few lines from there:

```
<form action="/Admin/UserMaint/9" id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="long-string-of-charaacters-here" /></form><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

So the __AjaxAntiForgeryForm is the very first thing on my page .. even before the html tag.

Here is the portion of my View that creates that:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

**-- EDIT 12/10/2014 @ 2:31 PM EST --**

After going through some of the comments made for this, particularly those by @Pointy, I have tried "flattening" my data. I have replaced my dataObject logic with the following:

```
var dataObject = {
    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
    UserId: '@Model.UserId',
    Field1Dirty: ($('#FieldID').hasClass('DirtyField')) ? 1 : 0,
    Field1Old: $('#FieldID').attr('data-oldvalue'),
    Field1New: $('#FieldID').val(),
    -- etc --
};
```

However, even with completely flat data, I am still seeing the data passed as Request Payload and I am still getting nothing in the controller.

**-- EDIT 12/10/2014 @ 3:23 PM EST --**

Well .. now I'm completely lost. I edited my code to this:

```
var dataObject = {
    UserId: '9'
};
```

And it still gets sent as Request Payload. I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: You should be able to use your browser's developer tools to see exactly what the HTTP request looks like, so that you can verify that your page is *sending* the proper request.

Comment: FYI, I changed class SaveDataHelper to have MaintUserID be a string, just in case that was the problem (it was a long-shot .. I know) .. and there was no change.

Comment: Note that `var token = $("#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input").val();` will get the value of the first `<input>` element in the form. Is that really the right thing to do? Is the very first `<input>` the one that has your security token in it?

Comment: Do you have a `form` in this page? If so, when you inspect it, does it have the Anti Forgery hidden `input` there?

Comment: Also, as poited by @Pointy, this would be the correct way of getting its value: `$("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();`

Comment: @Pointy I have added the top of the results of "View Page Source" to the end of my post. I believe that answers your question.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I have added the top of the results of "View Page Source" to the end of my post. I believe that answers your question.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the outgoing HTTP request looks OK?

Comment: @Pointy So I just ran this and one other similar request, and they actually look very different. This one shows my data as "Request Payload" and the other one (that actually works) shows my data as "Form Data." Any idea why I'm seeing that discrepancy?

Comment: FYI, if I comment out "__RequestVerificationToken: token," in the dataObject and the "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]" filter, the controller is called, but the data is null.

Comment: Well now that I look at the way you're setting up your parameters, I think that's the problem. Your "dataObject" can't be converted by jQuery into a query string because of those nested objects.

Comment: @Pointy I tried adding `var changedFields = JSON.stringify(dirtyFields);` and sending that string instead of the array, but still getting nulls in my controller. I compared the code to a very similar call I'm doing elsewhere in the application, and they are functionally identical ... except that the other one is working.

Comment: @Pointy At this point I'm 90% sure that the correct symptom for this problem is that this call is sending the data as a "Request Payload" instead of "Form Data." All other calls in my app seem to be sending as "Form Data."

Comment: Right. If you give jQuery an object for the "data" property on your `$.ajax()` call, and the object doesn't look like a flat name/value map (where the values are either scalars or arrays), it passes the object as the payload instead of converting it to a query string. You'll have to figure out a way to post your "dirty field" list, perhaps as three separate array values (which jQuery *can* convert).

Comment: Edited question (added additional info) based on comments by @Pointy

Comment: Maybe it's because you're setting the `contentType` to `json`?  You don't want it sent as JSON, right?

Comment: @Pointy please post that last comment as the solution .. I believe I have the answer from that.

Comment: OK - let me check the jQuery source to make sure I understand what it's doing

Comment: @Pointy the problem was actually a typo - one that I never would have found without your last comment. In all my other ajax calls I had `dataType: 'json'` but in that one I had mistyped it as `contentType: 'json'`. As soon as you post as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outgoing `$.ajax()` call is coded with a `contentType` property. That affects the content type of the *request*, not the response.

I have not found in the jQuery source where and how that affects the HTTP request that gets made.

Comment: As I said in comments, that was the answer. I had mistyped `dataType` as `contentType` and never noticed it no matter how many times I looked over the code. Thank you very much!